# Compiling Jsoncpp in VS2012 64bit/CMake

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2012, jsoncpp

I am trying to do what I hoped would be an easy thing: download and compile the projects for Jsoncpp.

I am running on Windows 8.1 64 bit using VS2012 c++.
I am also using CMake 2.8.11.2 and Python34.

When I download jsoncpp and try to run the CMakefiles, I get the following error.

CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "1.4", but required
  is at least "2.6" (found C:/Python34)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:313 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPythonInterp.cmake:139 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  src/jsontestrunner/CMakeLists.txt:1 (FIND_PACKAGE)

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

I understood that Python was only required for the documentation so I also tried just ignoring this and compiling the jsoncpp projects.  When I do so, I get:

```
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: jsontest, Configuration: Release x64 ------
3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: test_lib_json, Configuration: Release x64 ------
2>Build started 8/13/2014 12:05:53 AM.
2>_PrepareForClean:
2>  Deleting file "x64\Release\jsontest.lastbuildstate".
2>InitializeBuildStatus:
2>  Touching "x64\Release\jsontest.unsuccessfulbuild".
3>Build started 8/13/2014 12:05:53 AM.
3>_PrepareForClean:
3>  Deleting file "x64\Release\test_lib_json.lastbuildstate".
2>ClCompile:
2>  main.cpp
3>InitializeBuildStatus:
3>  Touching "x64\Release\test_lib_json.unsuccessfulbuild".
3>ClCompile:
3>  jsontest.cpp
3>  main.cpp
2>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\jsoncpp\jsoncpp-master\makefiles\vs71\x64\Release\json_vc71_libmt.lib'
```

I am a newbie at CMake and jsoncpp so this may be simple.

Any help appreciated.

James

Comment: I see that for some reason the build is looking for a visual studio 2003 library instead of a 2012 library. Are you compiling and running cmake from a Visual Studio 2012 x64 command prompt?

Comment: Looks like you upgrade your environment. Check your paths and remove outdated software.

Comment: I am running CMake directly not through VS.  Also, I checked the paths and there is nothing referencing an earlier version of Python.

Comment: What leads you to believe that the build is looking for a VS2003 library?